# getJobExecutions from start time to end time

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my running Spring Batch system i want to get:

**jobExplorer.getJobExecutions** from start time to end time

Is there any exist API or i need to query the database manually?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504787/305142

To summarize, deploy [Spring Batch Admin](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/) and use Rest JSON API

```
/jobs/executions GET List all the job executions, in order of most recent to least
```